# I am trying to see duplicate rows in pandas but what I get in return are not duplicates?

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates

When I run the code

```
 print len(combined_dataframe[combined_dataframe.duplicated()])
 print sum(combined_dataframe.duplicated())
```

both tell me that I have 130,600 duplicate rows, so I wanted to see some of these duplicate rows. So I used the code

```
 print combined_dataframe[combined_dataframe.duplicated()].head()
```

and what it gives me in return is a dataset like this.

```
      article_ID user_id date_clicked article_id  send_time author_id topic_id  
514        224       1   2015-01-02         18 2015-01-02      3612        3   
515        224       1   2015-01-02        237 2015-01-02      9712       54   
516        224       1   2015-01-02        131 2015-01-02       481       60   
517        224       1   2015-01-02        277 2015-01-02      8842       57   
518        224       1   2015-01-02        124 2015-01-02      3664       95
```

clearly they are not duplicates since I can see different values in the 4th, 6th and 7th columns. I didn't specify any columns to look for duplicates so it should return me only rows which are all duplicates, right?

Or is there something wrong with the code that I am using to view the duplicate rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need add parameter `keep=False` to function [`duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html), if you need all duplicated rows:

```
print combined_dataframe[combined_dataframe.duplicated(keep=False)].head()
```

[Docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html):

> **keep** : {‘first’, ‘last’, False}, default ‘first’
>
> first : Mark duplicates as True except for the first occurrence.
> last : Mark duplicates as True except for the last occurrence.
> False : Mark all duplicates as True.

You get only first duplicated rows, because `keep : 'first'` is default value.

If rows are still different, try [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html).

Comment: Thanks, sorting helped, even though I can't understand where the duplicates are coming from, considering I removed all before merging the files.